# Is there a limited lifetime for the staging area in Git?

Tags: git, staging

I've just started learning Git. For now what I know is that before commit to the main repository, "snapshots" get added to the staging area. The question is, should I care about how long those "snapshots" can reside in the staging area? Will all the data get erased when I, say, turn my PC off?

If there is no lifetime for staging area contents, how does it differ from the repository itself? In this case, to me it looks like a second repository.

Comment: No, there is no concept of a time limit.

Comment: No, there is no lifetime and they will not go away if you turn your PC off. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228209/whats-the-use-of-the-staging-area-in-git and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635458/what-is-the-difference-between-the-working-directory-and-the-git-index and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57940010/git-working-directory-vs-staging-area-vs-local-repo-vs-git-folder

Answer (score 4):

[Timothy Truckle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70442363/1256452) is correct, but I'll add a few items:

- `git worktree add` creates not just a new working tree, but also a new index / staging-area that is private to that new working tree.
- There is a bug—a rather bad one—in Git versions 2.5 through 2.14, fixed in 2.15, associated with this.

The bug is that the index / staging-area in these added working trees *does* have a limited lifetime, by mistake.  Some files stored in it can be destroyed by mistake after 14 days pass.  So if you have a pre-2.15 Git, and use `git worktree add`, get your work done within this added working tree within two weeks.  (Or update to a corrected Git: updating suffices to keep their added index files intact; you need not do anything with the added work-trees; you just need to upgrade before the staging area gets whacked.)

## Optional additional reading

> If there is no lifetime for staging area contents, how does it differ from the repository itself?  In this case, to me it looks like a second repository.

A Git repository is, to a first approximation, a big database of *commits*.  These are numbered (by big, ugly, random-looking hash IDs) and Git pulls them out of the database by that number.  So you must provide the hash ID of any commit *to* Git, before Git can find the commit.  We have branch and other names so that we, mere humans, can use a secondary database—one that turns names into numbers—to help us (and Git) find the commits without having to memorize random-looking hash IDs.

The *index*, *staging area*, or (to use the oldest and worst term for it) *cache*, in Git is not actually a commit.  It has a small collection of miscellaneous jobs, so there's no single perfect description of it, but the reason *staging area* is a pretty good name for it is that it holds, at all, times, a *proposed next commit*.

(Sometimes—during conflicted merges—it holds a mess, which can't actually be committed.  But even then it holds a sort of proposed next commit.  It's just that the proposal has *too much* in it, including extra stuff that can't be committed.  In this case `git status` will tell you about *unmerged* files.  But if we ignore this particular case, and ignore the other extra roles that the index plays—such as to speed up `git status`'s handling of *untracked* files with an optional "untracked cache", for instance—that "proposed next commit" description holds up pretty well.)

Since a *repository* is a database of commits, and the index / staging-area is merely a *single proposed commit* that's not actually committed yet, there's a big difference between the index and a repository.  The fact that there's just the one index—or more precisely, one per added working tree, plus one original one<sup>1</sup>—means that you can only hold at most one extra commit here (or N+1 where N is the number of added working trees).

It's worth looking at how `git status` works here too:

- There's a *current commit*, findable using the name `HEAD`.  This commit—like all commits—is read-only: it literally can't change.  (You can switch to some other current commit, i.e., change *which commit is current*, but you can't change any commits' content.)
- Then there's the *proposed next commit* in the index / staging-area.  You *can* change what's in here.  They're stored in a pre-Git-ified format, ready to go into a commit: the files are already de-duplicated and Git-ized, once they're in the index / staging-area.
- Last, there's some set of files that you're working on / with, in your working tree.  You *can* change these too, because these are just ordinary files.  *Any* program on your computer can read or write these, not just Git.

So when you run `git status`, it gets around to doing *two* diffs, not just one.  The first diff compares the files in `HEAD` to the files in the index / staging area.  **For each file that is the same, Git says nothing.  For any file that is different, Git says `staged for commit`.**

Having run that diff, `git status` also runs a *second* diff, to compare the files in the index to those in the working tree.  Once again, for files that are the *same*, Git says nothing.  **For any file that is different, Git says `not staged for commit`.**

The reason this sort of shadowy "hide the files" dance is useful becomes clear when you have a large project.  Say there are 10,000 files in the current commit.  There are therefore 10,000 files (plus or minus one or two maybe) in the index, and 10,000 files (plus or minus a few, plus maybe a bunch of *untracked* files that you will never commit) in the working tree.  If `git status` reported (twice!) on all 10k files every time, how would you find the useful data—that you changed three of them, for instance—in all the noise?  You *want* a useful summary, not a list of 9997 unmodified files with three useful names hidden in them.

(If you want the raw list, `git ls-files --stage` gets it.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The reason for this somewhat klunky wording (why not just "number of working trees"?) is that Git has so-called *bare* repositories, which have no working tree at all.  These repositories still have an index.  So in a bare repo, we have one staging area, but zero work-trees.  Add three work-trees and we now have four staging areas with three work-trees.

I'd argue that it was fundamentally a mistake to have the initial working tree and index/staging-area in *any* repository, and that all repositories should *start* "bare" and then have working trees added, perhaps one by default, but still as an add-on.  A truly bare repo would therefore have no index and *all* working trees would be "added on", rather than having a weird distinction between the "primary working tree" of a non-bare repo and all the add-on ones.  But it's long past too late for this.  It would be a distinction without a difference to most users, but it would solve a few thorny internal issues, one of which is causing a lot of discussion on the mailing list right now.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind, that there is only one staging area.
This means, that the content of the staging area will be taken to another branch when you switch branches.
Git will even refuse to switch (unless you give the force switch  `-f`) when the target branch conflicts with the staging area just like it does when local changes conflict.

Use the staging area to prepare *clean commits*.
A *clean commit* is when your project compiles an all automated (unit)tests pass.

Sometimes you may create bigger changes having your code base not compiling  but some part of your work should be secured.
Especially when doing *Test Driven Development* you often experience the opposite: You've completed a microcycle (code base compiles and the unittest(s) passes), but your current unittest is not jet completed.

In both situations you stage the current state (`git add`).

As soon as your task is completed (project compiles and all test pass) you add the latest local changes to the stage and make a commit of the staged state.

Yes, this way you will get lots of rather small commits.
But this is something good:

- small commits need less words to describe them -> first line of commit message usually is sufficient. This way `git log -oneline` shows a documentation of what you have done.
- small commits have less potential for conflicts on `rebase`
- small commits make it easier to find a certain change in a file because there are not so many files changed an the commit message can give a better clue which commit may have that change.
- small commits make it easier to transfer changes from one branch to another by *cherry-picking*.

And after all you can still *squash* them later to one single commit if needed.

Comment: It's fine to commit work in progress to your feature branch. It can be squashed later, and facilitates things like moving your work between computers. You can't push the staging area.

Comment: @MadPhysicist it depends what you consider *work in progress*. I personally would not check in something that could cause trouble when checked out by others especially a not compilable state or failing automated tests. Cross your heart:: do you always remember that there is a squash to be done before pushing?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I think this highly depends on your organization's process. I *push* WIP commits all the time to my branch, and I rebase my branches multiple times per day and re-push. I promise you I **always** remember to `rebase -i` my commits before I *complete a PR* into a shared branch though. We name our branches prefixed with `user/first.last/*` to indicate they are likely getting rewritten often, so everyone knows not to base their stuff off of `user/*` branches, unless they are collaborating with someone.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I suppose this hinges on what is meant by "check in". In my organization "check in" means complete a PR into a shared branch. Pushing commits on your own branch is simply "saving your work" off of your own machine.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle. TTT pretty much covers it. My "saved work" is labeled "WIP", and we generally know not to expect it to pass tests and sometimes not to build. We generally squash the entire feature when merging into a shared branch.

Comment: @TTT my point is: when all commits of my feature branche are "clean" then I have a perfect check whether during rebase  conflict resolution was successful or not: since both, the target branch and the conflicting commit  where clean  (compiles an all test pass) the conflicting commit must be clean again  after conflict resolution. Its more about to ease **my** work...